# returning function output in variable

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function based on the viewport-size of your browser and returns an `"X1"`, `"X2"` or `"X3"` which would be used in my HTML `srcset` attribute so the correct image-size gets loaded.

This is what i have right now.

```
  window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
    if(typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined'){
      winw = window.innerWidth
    console.log(winw)
    return winw
  }     
})
```

I've tried **Lots** of things, I've tried giving the function a name and attribute, I've tried to put the whole method in a variable and bunch of other things.

The `console.log(winw)` does give me the right output, and it also updates the result which is what i want (for responsive reasons) but I can't seem to store the output in a variable outside the scope of the function.

I either get an `Undefined` or an `*variable* already/not declared`

Comment: can you please share a bit more code so that we can see the problem you're facing. In particular, you don't show where `winw` is declared.

Comment: *"which would be used in my HTML srcset attribute so the correct image-size gets loaded."* The browser will do this automatically. Not quite sure why you are needing JavaScript for that. Maybe this helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Comment: @RobinZigmond This is all the code. i've just made a JS file to write this functionality. I couldn't get past the first step to write the rest >_<''

Comment: @FelixKling I know it does. but i didn't like the fact that you have to write the same line and the image-source with "1X, 2X, 3X" over and over again for every image so i decided to write an if or switch to handle that.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I did try`let winw` in and outside the function but got an error so I removed it.

Comment: @RobinZigmond excuse me, it wasn't because of an error. i removed it because it didn't give me any log in the console.

Comment: If you want different images for different pixel ratios (1x, 2x, etc), then the window width won't help. You may be looking for `window.devicePixelRatio` ?

Comment: *"but I can't seem to store the output in a variable outside the scope of the function."* If you declare the variable `winw` outside of the function then your code will work. The problem may be with how/when you use that variable. It's not going to be set until the `resize` event triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `winw` in the parent scope where you want to access it, this way you don't have to return anything in the listener (as pointed out by @FelixKling, addEventListener doesn't take any return value - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp).

```js
let winw = undefined;

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    winw = window.innerWidth  
})
window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
    console.log('Resize event is fired')
    winw = window.innerWidth
    console.log(winw);
})

/* Timeout for the log here because console.log() alone
 would be fired before 'load' */
setTimeout(function(){ console.log(winw); }, 1000);
```

This works in my browser on load, same would apply for resize on resize.

Comment: As i commented before to Robin, I've tried a `let winw` but it didn't work. it just says undefined. and i get no log when i resize my browser. it's also problematic if it doesn't work unless I resize it.

Comment: So you may also use the 'load' event and not only resize https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load

Comment: Check my answer I edited it. Can't tell you what doesn't work if you don't post your code sorry!

Comment: Thanks but, this code only runs when loading the page (once). it doesn't work when i resize..

Comment: I think you guys misunderstood. The Code above is all i have. what i want to achieve. is stated in the first sentence. and what i can't get to work is in the title. i want to have my output of the function update in a variable. so i can use that in a statement. I appreciate the help, i hope i am clear.

Comment: @user10515430: You cannot return the value from an event handler. Were do you think it would return to? You are not calling the handler, the browser is.

Comment: @user10515430: Ok, trying to help I understand your issue now, I will try to implement it with html and come back to you

Comment: @FelixKling So I cannot store a value from an event handler like a listener in a variable??

Comment: @user10515430 that is what the above code does, winw is stored, you can access it. Try it in your developer console.

Comment: @user10515430: You can. An event handler is a function like any other. All the same scoping rules apply. But you cannot **`return`** it (I mean, you can, but it's not going to be returned to any code you control).

Comment: Console.log(winw) does not give me anything Outside the function _console says undefined_. but it does inside, inside the function it updates the value when i resize my window. i need to access that value in a variable outside the scope so i can use that value in another statement.

Comment: Try to set the html srcset= attribute each time the 'resize' or 'load' event is fired

Comment: @FelixKling So correct me if I'm wrong. I can store the value of a handler in a variable to use it right?? that is my main problem right now. So how do I store the value of this even handler to use it outside of the function in a different statement?

Comment: @user10515430: Like you have it. Add a `var winw;` before the call to `addEventListener`. I don't think it's the assignment that is the problem. I think you are trying to read the variable too early.

Comment: @FelixKling Ok so like before i added a `let winw` and indeed like you've said I've probably read the var too early. but when i manually log winw, i get the value followed by _undefined_. Why is that?

Comment: @user10515430: Can't say without seeing a complete example.

Comment: Juste made you a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/4qyqx014r7 . Background color will change on window resize. You can play with it, use winw, etc. This example doesn't use winw

Comment: Thank you FelixKling and QuentinC You both gave me the answers i was looking for.